# Protractor test does not finish, seems to loop until the jasmine timeout error hits

Tags: protractor

I feel pretty dumb to not be able to get the most basic protractor test to work. Given protractor 5.4.1 i have a spec.js

```
describe('my example tests', () => {
  const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    it('tests google', async () => {
      await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
      await browser.get("https://google.com");
      await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('input')));
      await element(by.css("input")).click();});});
```

and a conf of

```
exports.config = {

  directConnect: true,
  specs: ['tests/**/*.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
  },

  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 40000
  }
};
```

when running `protractor conf.js` the browser opens, goes to the page and then nothing happens until the 40s jasmine timeout hits. What I get are ~25 warnings per second
`W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, input) - the first result will be used`
as if some command is running in an endless loop until I get an error `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.` which does not tell me much and is hard to google.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: it looks like the first input field on the page is hidden, which would explain why waiting for its visibility fails. Try looking for the one with name "q"

Comment: so await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.name('q')))); and await element(by.name('q')).click();

Comment: wait what o.o you are totally correct, it's the wait for visability... wtf do I only get such a generic error message then and not something like "timeout waiting for element to be visible" -.- do you want to create an answer i can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Google page, the locator $('input') matches many elements, which is why you got the warning. The first one was used, but unfortunately, the first one was hidden. so `await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('input')));` failed, which gave the timeout error.
Using a locator that locates a unique and not hidden input element on the page, like `element(by.name('q'))` ought to work better.

I like the [Hetzner cloud protractor test helper](https://github.com/hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper) which provides wrappers like waitToBeDisplayed whose error reporting is less generic, if I recall correctly (it has been a while since I used it).